# Onclick of a button run a function - not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, onclick

html:

```
<button id="go-btn">GO BUTTON!</button>
```

javascript:

```
function hi(){
    alert("hi");
}

document.getElementById("go-btn").onclick = hi();
```

When I refresh the page the alert pops up before I click the button. Why is this happening? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are calling it while the assignment:

```
document.getElementById("go-btn").onclick = hi();
```

Just remove the `()` and you assign the `hi`-function to the `onclick`-handler.

```
document.getElementById("go-btn").onclick = hi;
```

Currently you are assigning the **RESULT** of `hi()` to the `onclick`-handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function hi(){
    alert("hi");
}

document.getElementById("go-btn").onclick = hi;
```

Notice how I removed the `()` from the assignment. You were calling the function immediately on load.

Answer (score 0):

You need to say:

```
document.getElementById("go-btn").onclick = function(){hi();}
```

Otherwise it will call the `hi()` function other than setting it `onclick`.

Another way to do this is:

```
document.getElementById("go-btn").onclick = hi;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var hi = function(){
    alert("hi");
}

document.getElementById("go-btn").onclick = hi();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("go-btn").onclick = hi;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your function call `hi()` into an anonymous function :

```
document.getElementById("go-btn").onclick = function() {hi()};
```