# Button link JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a table of buttons (in HTML using JS), each with an id that I can control and this is what I have achieved so far. The problem is that I need to redirect the user to a page by pressing any button in the table, but when compiling, the page that appears is the one I want to redirect instead of the main one (I use onload () to load the function, if that helps ...).

Here is my code:

```js
function tabla() {
  var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
  x.setAttribute("id", "miTabla");

  document.body.appendChild(x);

  var cont = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var y = document.createElement("TR");
    y.setAttribute("id", "fila" + i)
    document.getElementById("miTabla").appendChild(y);

    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      var a = document.createElement("TD");
      a.id = "miTD";
      var z = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      z.className = "btn";
      z.id = "Btn" + i + j;
      z.innerText = "Plaza " + n(cont);
      a.appendChild(z);
      document.getElementById("fila" + i).appendChild(a);
      document.getElementById("Btn" + i + j).onclick = Datos;
      cont++;
    }
  }
}

function n(numero) {
  return (numero < 10 ? '0' : '') + numero
}

function Datos() {
  window.location.replace("Datos.aspx");;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>

    <style>
        th {
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

        td {
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 8px;
            width: 100px;
        }

        .btn {
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          margin-right: 10px;
          width: 70px;
          height: 40px;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>

        
    <body onload= "tabla()"></body>
     

</html>
```

Comment: Try this: `ocument.getElementById("Btn" + i + j).onclick = Datos;`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: @mplungjan This problem is more than a simple typographical error. It's cause by a misunderstanding of what a function reference is.

Comment: The dupe and the above comment gave the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When registering functions as event callbacks, you aren't trying to invoke the function, you only want to reference it:

Change this:

```
document.getElementById("Btn" + i + j).onclick = Datos();
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("Btn" + i + j).onclick = Datos;
```

The parenthesis at the end is causing the `Datos` function to run immediately and change your location.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783476/onclick-of-a-button-run-a-function-not-working and already answered in comment - Please hammer close

Comment: Not working, it doesn´t redirect but now the buttons aren´t appearing, probably something else is wrong. I´m gonna look for the error

Comment: @DavidGomez Yes, that is a different issue. You are calling your `table` function from somewhere, right?

Comment: @ScottMarcus i solved it right now, the problem was in the order of `document.getElementById("fila" + i).appendChild(a);` and
     `document.getElementById("Btn" + i + j).onclick = Datos;`